# How to change style class of td in table using SAPUI5

Tags: css, html-table, sapui5

In SAPUI5, there is no APIs to change anything the table cell itself.
The following code is to modify the style of the cell and control in the cell in formatter, but both of them adds style class to the control, not td.
Could anyone indicate how to change td style in a table?

```
editableFormatter: function(v, control) {
    if(sap.ui.getCore().byId("btnEdit").getText()==="Edit") {
        control.getParent().getCells()[2].addStyleClass('readonly');
        control.addStyleClass('readonly');
    }
}
```

Comment: what control are you using? The code snippet is very short to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you please add some more code? Maybe some jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can apply readOnly using CSS. You need to use `JQuery` or `Javascript` to make the field readOnly.

Example:

```
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

A table cell (`<TD>`) is not a SAPUI5 control, so getting the SAPUI5 parent from a `Text` will return the bound `item` (or HTML `<TR>`)

To get to the actual TD DOM object, first get the SAPUI control, and then its DOM parent using its jQuery object:

```
var td = control.getParent().getCells()[2].$().parent();
```

...and to set a css style to this TD DOM object, use standard Javascript:

```
td.className = td.className + " myCSSStyle";
```

*PS note the space before the style classname*

Answer (score 0):

Definitely we need to manipulate DOM after document is ready,
I managed to get the data array and get cells using jquery:

```
for(var i = 0, j = parameters.length; i < j; i++) {
    $('#'+table.getId()+'-rows-row'+i+'-col'+idx).addClass('readonly');
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there are better solutions.

Best Regards,
Mingquan